# how does visual studio know which assemblies in a NuGet package to reference?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

A NuGet package is published with many, many assemblies. Not all assemblies in a NuGet package need to be referenced in the `*.csproj` in Visual Studio. How does Visual Studio determine which assembly to reference? Is the logic for this in nuget.exe or is it in some NuGet API?

Comment: What do you mean "not.. need to referenced"? are you referring to the new csproj format that calculates transitive dependencies?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does Visual Studio determine which assembly to reference? Is the logic for this in nuget.exe or is it in some NuGet API?

This determine should be a combination of nuget.exe and NuGet API in Visual Studio. Visual Studio use NuGet.exe to download the package, then use the [NuGet API in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio#ivspackageinstaller-interface) to install the corresponding assemblies to the project.

First, NuGet supports putting multiple versions of the same library in a single package when using the **convention-based working directory**. So we will use **different case-sensitive framework names** to specifically target multiple frameworks with subfolders under `lib`:

```
lib\{framework name}[{version}]
```

Then we will use NuGet API in Visual Studio to install the package to project, it tries to **match the framework name of the assembly with the target framework of the project**.

Besides, NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio is an instance of the combination of nuget.exe and nuget API, so Visual studio knows which assemblies in a NuGet package to reference.

You can refer to the NuGet document [Supporting multiple .NET framework versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks) for more detail info.

Comment: If you want to be "more correct", there's also the `ref/` folder when you don't want all the things in `lib/` to be referenced or for bait-and-switch packages..

Comment: your answer has directed me here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3062

Comment: the scriptcs folks wrote this without Visual Studio concerns: https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/blob/76ec57b642be836eaa7fd2a9ffa10fb1f9a60eae/src/ScriptCs.Hosting/Package/NugetInstallationProvider.cs